# How to run program in R every 10 seconds without Scheduler?

Tags: r

I am creating a program in R to get data off an api. Since it is real time pricing data, I need to run the program every 10 seconds.

I was wondering:

1. What is the most effective way to do this?
2. What is the easiest way to add this data to an excel doc?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Sys.sleep()`

```r
i = 1
while(TRUE){
    if (i %% 11 == 0){
        #write.table()  #But maybe you would want to write results
                        #to a table after certain number of iteration

        break           #A condition to break out of the loop
    }

    print(i)            #Run your code
    Sys.sleep(time = 1) #Time in seconds
    i = i + 1
}
```