# Simulate incoming data after some time and save intermediate results

Tags: r

I want to simulate incoming data and do something with it.

For example I have this (final) data frame.

```
my_data <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                  person = sample( LETTERS[1:3], 10, T),
                  score = sample(50:100, 10, T))
```

Now I want get every row individually after some time (e.g. 15 seconds) and do something (e.g. calculate the average). So I will have this, then calculate the avg score.

```
> my_data2
  id person score
1  1      C    54 

mean(my_data2$score)
```

and after some time this and so on.

```
> my_data2
  id person score
1  1      C    54
2  2      B    68

mean(my_data2$score)
```

I thought about looping through `my_data`. I tried this [How to run program in R every 10 seconds without Scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679147/how-to-run-program-in-r-every-10-seconds-without-scheduler) and it only gives me the final result, but I want to work with the intermediate results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no time-related variables in your data. What is the indicator of time?

Comment: The original data has a time related variable. Every person (can occur multiple times) has a time id.

Comment: Is your data changing? You indicate you want to do something like schedule a task every 10 seconds but your example seems static. Could you produce the expected output? You should include `set.seed(123)` so your dataset is reproducible.

Comment: I have a data set for testing purposes, but the real data set will have the same variables just other values. The real data will get new rows every some seconds or minutes. I do not know the final number of rows in advance nor the exact time when a new row will be generated. So when the first row arrives I will do something, then when the second row is generatred OR after a time set by me e.g. every 15 seconds I will do the same but with both rows, and so forth.  I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: How are you importing your data? You could use the answer you linked to continually read in a csv . E.g., `for (i in 1:30) {my_data2 = read.csv(mycsv); mean(my_data2$score); Sys.sleep(10);}`